# Enforce strict inheritance based on accessor method

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, polymorphism, abstract-class

Given that a base class is defined as,

```
abstract Base{
    protected int field;
    protected int getter(){
        return this.field;
    }
    ...
}
```

With the intention of classifying a sub-type, on the basis of this getter, I created an interface like,

```
interface MyFieldGettable{
    public int getter();
}
```

And I was happy creating a sub-types like,

```
class CantGetField extends Base{
    ....
}
```

And since, the base version already prints the field, let's make the complement sub-type like,

```
class CanGetField extends Base implements MyFieldGettable {
    public int getter(){
        return this.getter();
    }
}
```

Now, somewhere in a piece of code there is a `List<Base>`, and I want to segregate the two types, and check fields of `CanGetField` type. Hence, I write,

```
for(Base b:listOfBase){
    if(b instanceof CanGetField){
        int field = ((CanGetField)b).getter();
```

And, if any of you would have guessed by now. This blows into `StackOverflowError`. Now, I can get around this by correcting the definition of class `CanGetField` as,

```
class CanGetField extends Base implements MyFieldGettable {
    public int getter(){
        return this.field;
    }
}
```

Or, I can change the name of getter method in interface, and delegate all calls in sub-types to base method. But, that will result in lot of redundant code in sub-types.

Is there any other solution to this.

Comment: `return super.getter()`, presumably?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth you're 49 seconds ahead of me :(

Comment: Don't I look so silly. Was thinking hell & heaven about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This blows into StackOverflowError. Now, I can get around this by
>   correcting the definition of class CanGetField as,

`getter()` does an infinite recursive call here :

```
class CanGetField extends Base implements MyFieldGettable {
    public int getter(){
        return this.getter();
    }
}
```

If you want to override the `getter()` method to only change the modifier and  and not its behavior, you could call `super.getter()`:

```
class CanGetField extends Base implements MyFieldGettable {
    public int getter(){
        return super.getter(); // super implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: And use `super.getter()` instead.

Comment: He wants to override it with exactly the same implementation. It is useless.

Comment: Exactly, I got the cause of `StackOverflowError`. Anyways, thanks for the input.

Comment: The method is implemented but it's not `public`. The motivation was to leverage the method as a difference from other sub-types.

Comment: @soufrk Ok I understand. So     `public int getter(){
        return super.getter();
    }` should be enough

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by users, in the question's comments itself. This is what I was looking for,

```
class CanGetField extends Base implements MyFieldGettable {
    public int getter(){
        return super.getter();
    }
}
```